# Identify a cell in a table

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have multiple cells all with a button. Created in `SimpleTableCell.xib` with the buttons refrencing outlet `nav` for `SimpleTableCell.h` `SimpleTableCell.m`. These cells are then called in `ImagesTableViewController.m` and `ImagesTableViewController.h` like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

    SimpleTableCell *cell = (SimpleTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

NSString *stringy = @"http://www.example.co.uk/";
    NSString *link = [stringy stringByAppendingString: images[indexPath.row]];
    NSString* encodedString = [link stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

SDImageCache *imageCache = [SDImageCache sharedImageCache];
    [imageCache queryDiskCacheForKey:encodedString done:^(UIImage *image, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {

        if (image){
            cell.thumbnailImageView.image = image;
        }else{
            [cell.thumbnailImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:encodedString] completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {
                [imageCache storeImage:image forKey:encodedString];

            }];

        }


    }];

[cell.nav addTarget:self action:@selector(naviguate) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

}
```

where `naviguate` is:

```
-(void)naviguate{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay:0
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^{

                         [_tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 569, _tableView.frame.size.width, _tableView.frame.size.height)];
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"link" sender:self];
                     }];

}
```

I am wanting to associate the `indexPath.row` when clicking on the cell button. So that I can identify which cell was pressed.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could change your handler to accept the `UIButton` which triggered the event:

```
-(void)naviguate:(id)sender
```

Remembering to change your `addTarget` `selector` to tell it to expect parameters:

```
[cell.nav addTarget:self 
             action:@selector(naviguate:) 
   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

You could then subclass your `UIButton` and add the index path as a property which you set when the cell is created.

In the handler the subclassed `UIButton` is passed as the sender and you can access the index path property value.

Comment: how do you subclass your button and add the index path as a property which you set when the cell is created.

Comment: Can't edit my answer so have to do it here. Create a new class which subclasses UIButton and add the index path property. In your SimpleTableCell.xib select your UIButton and in attribute inspector change the class from UIButton to your new class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `tag` property on the button to store your row.  In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` -

```
[cell.nav addTarget:self action:@selector(naviguate:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
cell.nav.tag=indexPath.row;
```

Then in your event handler you receive the sending button and you can simply retrieve the tag

```
-(void)naviguate:(id)sender {

  UIButton *theButton=(UIButton *)sender;

  // You can now get the row by accessing theButton.tag

  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                      delay:0
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{

                     [_tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 569, _tableView.frame.size.width, _tableView.frame.size.height)];
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"link" sender:self];
                 }];

}
```